# Lighttpd - add canonical headers to www pages

Tags: lighttpd, canonical-link

This is not the classic redirect www to non-www but rather I would like to add canonical headers to all www requests pointing to the non-www page, for example:

Request for https://www.example.com/index.html => Add canonical header to https://example.com/index.html

I have tried to use the generic redirect but it does not look right and it does not evaluate the %1/$1

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
  setenv.add-response-header += ( "Link" => "<https://%1/$1>; rel='canonical'" )
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I went with the mod_magnet / Lua route which involved two simple steps.

1. Edit the lighttpd.conf to add both the mod_magnet module and a conditional for when the requested host has www.

> ```
> server.modules = ( mod_magnet, )
> $HTTP["host"] ~= "^www\.(.*)$" {
>   magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ( "/path/to/canonical.lua" )
> }
> ```

2. Writing the simple canonical.lua file (note that I added a check for www. but this is not required as the file is only executed when the host has it!)

> ```
> function string.starts(String,Start)
>  return string.sub(String,1,string.len(Start))==Start
> end
>
> if string.starts(lighty.request['Host'], "www.") then
>   lighty.header["Link"] = "<https://"..string.sub(lighty.request['Host'],5)..lighty.env["request.uri"]..">;rel=\"canonical\""
> end
> ```

Comment: Thank you for posting your result so that others may reference it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how lighttpd mod_setenv works. https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSetenv does not describe that syntax.

Also, the += in a different condition block in lighttpd.conf may not do what you think it does.  The += is for setenv in the same condition block.  Only one setenv (set) from one condition block applies to a request.

All that said, one correct solution does not use lighttpd mod_setenv:

In lighttpd, you can use **mod_magnet** to execute a few lines of custom lua code.  With that you can make a wide set of arbitrary changes, including setting response headers after matching against the lighty.env["request.uri"].
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModMagnet

Comment: Thanks. 1. The `+=` as presented in the question actually added the response header (but did not evaluate the `%1/$1`). I'll look at mod_magnet thought that is a bit more involved than I hoped.